# How to hide scrollbars in Android WebView through React Native

Tags: android, webview, react-native

Using WebView in React Native 0.26 and on Android the scroll bars always flash up when the content loads, as we are showing a few on a page this is very distracting.

React Native lists ScrollEnabled as iOS only, so is there anyway to hide these scrollbars on Android?

Many thanks,
Vince

Comment: Didnt find any method inside react native WebView.android.js file which will help in hiding the scrollbar.. I think currently hiding scrollbar is not supported in android

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

This is currently only available for IOS devices per react-native (v0.48) documentation on
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#scrollenabled

> scrollEnabled?: bool
>
> Boolean value that determines whether scrolling is enabled in the
>   WebView. The default value is true.

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: thanks for the tips i think i fixed it for future use